# Como eu crio uma janela flutuante em html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Eu preciso de uma janela com conteúdo em tabela que abra quando eu clicar em um link e tenha um botão de fechar.

Comment: Eu quero criar uma janela que abra quando eu clicar em um link e feche com outro botao.

Comment: É isto que pretende: http://jsfiddle.net/f9s5b1ss/ ? Ou quere que o botõ esteja na página e não na janela?

Comment: Botão embutido na janela, assim como nos anuncios do "hot ads words"

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu seu problema marque ela como aceita. Leia mais em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117)

Comment: Vc não precisa aprender a fazer uma janela flutuante se tiver o psafe instalado. Super indico!

Comment: @RobertaBarreto psafe? poderia dar uma indicação mais precisa?

Answer (score 2):

#### Aqui fica um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/a33p4wy3/

O modal do jQuery já tem por defeito um botão para fechar. Se quiser fazer o seu próprio precisa de invocar o método `$('#dialog').dialog('close');`. Assim qualquer código ou oscultador de eventos que corra esse código fecha o modal.

Código no meu exemplo:

```
jQuery('#open').click(function () {
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
jQuery('#close').click(function () {
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Estou implementando o código no meu site!

Comment: @Sergio detalhe, no seu fiddle o botão externo `Fechar janela` não está funcionando, poderia trocar o seletor para `.close` e usar como `class` que funcionária direitinho. exp: http://jsfiddle.net/a33p4wy3/8/

Answer (score 1):

Quando eu preciso fazer o que você necessita eu uso uma `<div>` com style `'display:none'` como padrão e uso jQuery para exibir e esconder com animação para ficar mais interessante.

vamos aos detalhes, dentro dessa div você cria todo o conteúdo que irá ser exibido, tabelas, forms, textos e btns, posicione um pequeno botão em alguma parte dessa div com 'x' ou o texto 'fechar', depois de ter preparado todo o layout desse box que irá ficar flutuante na tela *(style position:fixed;)* você ira criar os comandos para exibir e esconder, vou mostra o efeito mais simples do jQuery, coloque um ID no botão que será clicado para abrir o box **(idDoBotao)**, no ID do botão que fechará o box **(idDoBotaoFechar)** e na `<div>` **(idDaDiv)**, com jQuery faça o seguinte:

```
// Para exibir o box flutuante
$('#idDoBotao').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventdefault();
     $('#idDaDiv').fadeIn();
     // Ou
     //$('#idDaDiv').show();
});

// Para ocultar o box flutuante
$('#idDoBotaoFechar').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventdefault();
     $('#idDaDiv').fadeOut();
     // Ou
     //$('#idDaDiv').hide();
});
```

Ah, blz chinnon, montei aqui mas o box não esta flutuante, e ai???
Simples, o que faz o box ficar flutuante é o CSS, simplesmente coloque:

```
.boxFlutuante {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px -100px 0 0;
}
```

Isso vai fazer com que seu box fique flutuante na tela, de forma centralizada, se não quiser centralizar, remova o 'margin' e controle os 'left' e 'top' para posicionar da forma que desejar.

É necessário ter um conhecimento básico de HTML, CSS e jQuery, as funções jQuery que usei são as compatíveis com as versões atuais da biblioteca, caso tenha dúvida sobre elas leia a documentação no site oficial:

```
on(); 
fadeIn();
fadeOut();
show();
hide();
preventdefault();
```

Fiz um box desse flutuante no seguinte site, nessa mesma ideia sua, porem ao invés de exibir e ocultar ele com um botão eu calculo a barra de rolagem, quando você desce a página para ver o conteúdo ele exibe o box fixo do lado esquerdo, quando encosta no top novamente ele oculta o box, confira: www.imageriacriativa.com.br

---

Editado - 23/02/2015
Como colocar a ação em uma tag `<a>`?

Simples, escreva para abrir: `<a id="idDoBotao" href="#" title="">Botão Fechar</a>`
para fechar: `<a id="idDoBotaoFechar" href="#" title="">Botão Fechar</a>`

Usando o mesmo código jQuery explicado anteriormente, é possível colocar a ação em qualquer objeto HTML desde que ele tenha o `id=""` da ação definida no jQuery. Lembre-se de trocar os ID's **'idDoBotao'** e **'idDoBotaoFechar'** pelos ID's de sua preferência.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços...

Comment: E como eu ponho a ação fechar ou abrir em um "<a href="">?

Answer (score 1):

Caso você não queira ou possa usar um plugin como sugerido pelo @Sergio, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```js
var btAbrirModal = $("#btAbrirModal");
var modal = $("#modal");
var modalClose = $("#modal .modal-close");
var modalBackground = $("#modal .modal-bg");

btAbrirModal.click(function () {
    modal.fadeIn(500);
});

modalClose.click(function () {
    modal.fadeOut(500);
});

//Caso queira que o dialogo feche ao realizar um click fora dele.
//
//modalBackground.click(function () {
//    modal.fadeOut(500);
//});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.modal-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: gainsboro;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.modal-close {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btAbrirModal">Abrir Modal</button>
<div id="modal" class="hide">
    <div class="modal-bg"></div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
        <a class="modal-close">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```