# Caixa de aviso após clique em div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, queria saber como faço para quando alguém clicar em um botão abrir uma box no centro da página e que a página de fundo fique desfocada.

Tenho apenas o código do botão:

```
<a href="login.php"><div class="button"></a></a>
```

Eu queria também que a página Login.php aparecesse na box.

Comment: De uma olhada aqui, tem algo bem parecido com o que você deseja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32474/como-eu-crio-uma-janela-flutuante-em-html

Comment: Está buscando uma resposta que não utilize nenhuma biblioteca/framework Javascript?

Comment: Eu só queria que ao eu clicar em um botão, uma janela abrisse.

Comment: Luis, não resolveu meu caso. Não funcionou aqui

Comment: Utiliza Bootstrat ou poderia utilizar?

Comment: Hã? Não entendi.. Bootstrat?

Comment: King, de uma olhada: http://jsfiddle.net/a33p4wy3/8/

Comment: BootStrap é um Framework de front-end. Ele faz o que você necessita. Se puder utilizar elaboro uma resposta mostrando como fazer.

Comment: Pode usar qualquer coisa, contanto que funcione.

Comment: @King, você pode olhar a minha resposta em outro pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51706/2363

Comment: @King, você deve ter em mente que para a janela modal funcionar, você deve referenciar as bibliotecas necessárias, por exemplo, `JQuery`, `BootStrap`, ou então criar uma solução manualmente utilizando `JavaScript` puro

Comment: Toby, eu vi, mas nas hora que clico no botão não aparece nada.

Comment: Marcelo, tipo, eu não entendo muito disso. Só estou pedindo ajuda pra fazer haha

Comment: Sim @King, mas pra fazer, você deve entender o mínimo ;] dê uma lida -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Comment: isso tambêm pode ajudar: https://www.codigofonte.net/dicas/javascript/310_jquery-o-que-e-e-como-usar

Comment: Olá pessoal, obrigado, mas acho que já resolvi.

Comment: Se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, por favor, marque ela como correta.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você deve realizar o download dos arquivos necessário para a utilização do [Bootstrap](http://globocom.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html) e [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).
Após realizar o download, coloque os arquivos em seu projeto e referencie os arquivos na sua página que deseja utilizar o componente (modal).

Após realizado a referência, adicione este código em sua página.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Abrir 
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Título</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Coloque o texto aqui.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Neste link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) você encontra um exemplo de como ficaria a utilização, e no site possui outros componentes que pode lhe ser útil.

Comment: Obrigado aí cara.

Comment: Verifique se funciona, caso não retorne com a dúvida.

Comment: Mas no site do jQuery o que eu tenho que baixar?

Comment: vá no link http://jquery.com/download/ e clique em **Download the compressed, production jQuery 1.11.2**

Comment: Tipo, lá no site do jQuery tem muita coisa, e eu não sei o que baixar e tals...

Comment: Ah, obrigado, consegui :D

Answer (score 1):

Existem [vários *plugins*](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/modal/) para facilitar a criação de janela Modal. Um exemplo utilizando o [jBox](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox):

```js
$(function(){ 
    new jBox('Modal', {          // Tipo de componente
        width: 400,              // Largura
        height: 200,             // Altura
        attach: $('#login-btn'), // Elemento que quando clicado exibirá a janela
        title: 'Login',          // Título da janela
        content: $('.login')     // Conteúdo da janela
    });
});
```

```css
/** 
   O CSS não tem relevância, utilizei somente para tornar o exemplo
   mais "apresentável".
*/

.login {
    display: none
}

.login input[type='email'],
.login input[type='password'] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}

.login input[type='submit']{
    background: #2cc36b;
    border: none;
    color: #fff
}

.login input {
    margin: 2px 5%;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 90%
}

#login-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 45%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2cc36b
}
```

```html
<!-- Importando o plugin e JQuery-->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jboxcdn.com/0.3.2/jBox.css'/>
<script src='http://code.jboxcdn.com/0.3.2/jBox.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Conteúdo que será exibido dentro da janela modal. -->
<div class='login'>
    <form action='#'>
        <input type='email' placeholder='Email'/>
        <input type='password' placeholder='Senha'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Login'/>
    </form>
</div>


<!--  Elemento que irá disparar o evento para exibir a janela modal. -->
<div id='login-btn'>Clique para fazer Login</div>
```

---

<kbd>Bônus</kbd>: Se for do seu interesse, o mesmo *plugin* possui outras funcionalidades como: *tooltips*, janelas de confirmação, notícias, avisos. Vide [documentação](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox#jbox).

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de colocar os meus 2 cents aqui.

Como vejo que está iniciando ainda com javaScript, jQuery, etc... gostaria de lhe apresentar um Framework FrontEnd que na minha opinião (2 cents) é melhor que o Bootstrap.

**Zurb Foundation.**

Abaixo segue um exemplo de dialogo modal usando o mesmo (veja em **FullScreen**).

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-reveal-id="firstModal" class="radius button">Modal in a modal&hellip;</a>

<!-- Reveal Modals begin -->
<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>This is a modal.</h2>
  <p>Reveal makes these very easy to summon and dismiss. The close button is simply an anchor with a unicode character icon and a class of <code>close-reveal-modal</code>. Clicking anywhere outside the modal will also dismiss it.</p>
  <p>Finally, if your modal summons another Reveal modal, the plugin will handle that for you gracefully.</p>
  <p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal" class="secondary button">Second Modal...</a></p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="secondModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>This is a second modal.</h2>
  <p>See? It just slides into place after the other first modal. Very handy when you need subsequent dialogs, or when a modal option impacts or requires another decision.</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa simples e elegante, sem utilizar bibliotecas é utilizar os comandos `alert`, `prompt` ou `confirm` do `JavaScript`

```js
function teste1(){
  alert("Alerta simples!");  
}

function teste2(){
  var resultado = confirm("Alerta do tipo Confirme? Sim Não");
  if ( resultado == true ) {
    document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = "SIM";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = "NÃO";
  }
}

function teste3(){
  var algo = prompt('Alerta do tipo Escreva Algo');
  document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = algo;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="teste1()" value="alert()" />
<input type="button" onclick="teste2()" value="confirm()" />
<input type="button" onclick="teste3()" value="prompt()" />

<div id="teste"></div>
```